# req.getRequestDispatcher("file.html").include(req, resp);

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, requestdispatcher

I am trying to display the `file.html` file in a servlet using `getRequestDispatcher` with include method, but it is not working. Can anyone find out the reason behind this?

when I use the `file.jsp` file, It (`getRequestDispatcher`) is displaying the information. why the `getRequestDispatcher` function is not working for `*.html` files?

Can anyone give me the reason?

Thank you

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: this is that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295696/redirecting-to-the-root-url-in-servlet)