# Redirecting to the root URL in servlet

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, servlets, redirect

Hi I did simple web application with servlet, to serve login and welcome page based on the session available. I had attached the code below,

whenever the user types the URL `http://localhost:8888/`, he must take to the `dashboard` servlet (as mention in the `web.xml`)

**In the `dashboard servlet`,**  where session is checked

if the session is available, then I will serve `welcome.html` page,
else I redirect to `login servlet`

**In the `login servlet`,**

`GET` method,
if the user have the session I redirect to the `dashboard servlet` 
else I will the forward the `welcome.html` page

after user entry the information, it will post the information to the `login servlet` (i.e., POST)

`POST` method,
I will get the username and password from the request, I will check value is `admin` and `password`

if it is true create a session and redirect the user to the `dashboard servlet`
else I will redirect the user to the `login servlet`(GET Method)

web application should need to have only these 2 URL,

(1) `http://localhost:8888/`
(2) `http://localhost:8888/login`

user should not aware of the type of page I am serving to them(html or jsp) but I need to serve HTML page only(this my requirement)

when I start the app engine, At first the request send to dashboard then it is redirected to the `login servlet` but then its making loop for the dashboard once again,

I used `System.out.println()` to track the control my output is

```
The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Jul 25, 2017 11:12:55 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
login servlet get method
request no session
-->dashboard servlet
get method
no session,
```

> QUESTION:

How can solve this problem?

If I change url pattern in `web.xml` as `<url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>` and in the servlet whereever redirection to the `/` I changed to `/index` for the `dashboard servlet` it is working fine, but how can I make use of the "/" for servlet

I have attached the source code below,

**dashboard servlet**

package servlet;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DashboardServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("-->dashboard servlet");
        System.out.println("get method");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {          
            System.out.println("session is available");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/welcome.html").forward(req, resp);
        } else {
            System.out.println("no session,");
            resp.sendRedirect("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

**Login Servlet**

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("-->>>login servlet post method");
        String name = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("password")) {
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("sessionUserName", name);
            resp.sendRedirect("/");

        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect("/login");
        }
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("login servlet get method");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            System.out.println("request with session");
            resp.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            System.out.println("request no session");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.html").forward(req, resp);
        }

    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Dashboard</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.DashboardServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Dashboard</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application></application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        User name :<input type='text' name='username'>Password :<input
            type='password' name='password'><input type='submit'
            value='Submit'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>welcome here
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You should not check only whether session is null. You should put a value like 'logged_in' into session as attribute. Then, control it for deciding where to route.

Update:

As a quick solution, route doGet inside LoginServlet to doPost and change doPost as below:

```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("login servlet get method");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("sessionUserName")!=null) {
            System.out.println("request with session");
            resp.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {

            String name = req.getParameter("username");
            String password = req.getParameter("password");
            if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("password")) {
                session = req.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("sessionUserName", name);
                resp.sendRedirect("/");

            } else {
               System.out.println("request no session");
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.html").forward(req, resp);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: yes even I tried with session attribute, in if condition (`if (session != null && session.getAttribute("sessionUserName").equals("admin")) `) it is giving the same result @yılmaz

Comment: @Prakash if problem is solved, please mark it as solved.

Comment: Problem line is `req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.html").forward(req, resp);` and this is in doGet() in the `LoginServlet`, and also the problem is not solved, @yılmaz

Comment: It is forming a loop whenever the control comes to that line, I have shown that above( in my question), I just used `System.out.println()` to track that. @yılmaz